# How to use Cplex .dll file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dll, cplex, pulp

I am using cplex .dll file in python to solve a well-formulated lp problem using pulp solver. Here is the code

## here model is pulp object created using pulp library

When I run a.actualSolve(Model) I get following error from subprocess.py file.

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I tried with python 32 bit and 64 bit but couldn't solve it.

import pulp
a = pulp.solvers.CPLEX_CMD("cplex dll file location")

a.actualSolve(model)

I expect the cplex dll file to solve my formulated optimization model and give me a solution for all the variables.

Comment: Are you using a 32bit CPLEX dll?

Comment: No I am using 64 bit cplex dll

Comment: Do we need to add any or install cplex or any other library or tool

Answer (score 0):

The `CPLEX_CMD` solver is a wrapper around the [CPLEX Interactive](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/interactiveoptimizercommands.html), *not the DLL*. You can pass the path to the `cplex.exe` file to the constructor or just make sure that it is in your `PATH` (see [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)).

In order to use the CPLEX DLL file, you need to use the `CPLEX_DLL` solver (see the PuLP [source code](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/pulp/solvers.py)). You also need to edit the PuLP configuration file to point to the location of the CPLEX DLL file.

For example, on Windows, your `pulp.cfg` file might look like:

```
[locations]
...
CplexPath = cplex1290.dll
...
```

This assumes that the CPLEX binary directory is already in your `PATH` (exactly as with `cplex.exe` above). Alternately, you can specify the absolute path to `cplex1290.dll` in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Now pulp has documentation on connecting with several solvers, including CPLEX: https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_configure_solvers.html

First example for `CPLEX_CMD`:

```
path_to_cplex = r'C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\bin\x64_win64\cplex.exe'
import pulp as pl
model = pl.LpProblem("Example", pl.LpMinimize)
solver = pl.CPLEX_CMD(path=path_to_cplex)
_var = pl.LpVariable('a')
_var2 = pl.LpVariable('a2')
model += _var + _var2 == 1
result = model.solve(solver)
```